# What should be output size of image classifier model?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, image-classification

I'm performing an image classification task . Images are labeled as 0 1 2. Should be the size of the last linear layer in the model output be 3 or 1 ? In general, for a 3-class operation, the output is set to 3, and as a result of these three, the maximum probability is returned. But I saw that the last layer is set as 1 in some codes. I think it is actually logical. What do you think about ? ( Also I dont use softmax or sigmoid function in last layer.)

Comment: Where exactly did you see a multi classification model with only 1 output?

Comment: https://medium.com/@ksusorokina/image-classification-with-convolutional-neural-networks-496815db12a8 , https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-a-convolutional-neural-network-to-classify-photos-of-dogs-and-cats/

Answer (score 1):

To perform classification into `c` classes (`c` = 3 in your example) you need to predict the probability of each class, therefore you need to output a `c`-dim output.
Usually you do not *explicitly* apply `softmax` to the "raw predictions" (aka "logits") - the loss function usually does that for you in a more numerically-robust way (see, e.g., [`nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.7.1/generated/torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss.html#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss)).

After you trained the model, at *inference time* you can take `argmax` over the predicted `c` logits and output a single scalar - the index of the predicted class. This can only be done during inference since `argmax` is not a differentiable operation.